# jquery prevent multiple instances of plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to display and update a chart using the plugin http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/.  The plugin is initiated on page load but I need to allow users to update the data that powers the chart.  However, this functionality adds multiple charts everytime the update event is initiated.  I assume I need to somehow destroy the original instance of the plugin before updating the chart data and re-initiating it but there is nothing incorporated into the plugin to allow this.

Can anyone tell me what I need to add to my code to get this working?

```
            jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

                    var chartData = new Array([0]);
                     showChart(chartData);                  

                    jQuery('#update').live("click", function() {
                        var qtyArr = [];

                        jQuery('input[name=qty]').each(function(i) {

                              qty =  Number(jQuery(this).val());

                              if(qty > 0){
                                qtyArr.push(qty);
                              }

                         });



                        chartData = new Array(
                            [qtyArr]
                        );

                        showChart(chartData); 
                    });

               });

                 function showChart(chartData){

                    jQuery("#chart").jqBarGraph({
                        data: chartData,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 300
                    });               
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `empty()` before you call the plugin:

```
jQuery("#chart").empty().jqBarGraph({
  data: chartData,
  width: 200,
  height: 300
});
```

Comment: I have added empty() but this doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Hi,  I have just updated your fiddle to include a title on the chart, this shows the code replicating. http://jsfiddle.net/qrdwknzx/1/

Comment: updated the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qrdwknzx/2/). The problem is that the title will be inserted in front of the graph container (in the fiddle #divForGraph). Therefore simply remove the `prev()` element too (if you actually use the title)

Comment: I dont think its just the title.  If you view source you will see multiple elements for id=graphHolder4divForGraph

Comment: this plugin modifies the existing DOM in way which is nasty/unpredictable...
nevertheless here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/qrdwknzx/3/

Answer (score 1):

The plugin's demo page clears the chart and reinitialises it as follows :

```
$('#exampleSimple').html('');
$('#exampleSimple').jqbargraph({ data: arrayOfData });
```

`.empty()` should also work.

You probably want -

```
function showChart(chartData) {
    $('#chart').empty().jqBarGraph({
        data: chartData,
        width: 200,
        height: 300
    });
}
```

Comment: Tried using the first example but this doesnt make a difference.  tried the 2nd and I get "clear is not a function"

Comment: Doh! My bad, it's `.empty()` not `.clear()` - edited.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either, see discussion below.

Comment: Odd because `.html('')` works on the demo page. Take a look at the page source and see if you can spot something I didn't. http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/

Comment: The plugin uses `.jqbargraph()` whereas you use `.jqBarGraph()`. I wonder if you found a different version/fork of the plugin from the one I found.

Comment: yes there are two versions floating around.  Its sorted now, thanks for your help.